# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am training a multi-label text  classification . I am using PyTorch Lightning to train the model.

Here is the code:

````
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
dirpath="checkpoints",
filename="best-checkpoint",
save_top_k=1,
verbose=True,
monitor="val_loss",
mode="min"
)```

And i'm getting

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-73-9e7c38808397\> in \<cell line: 1\>()
\----\> 1 checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
2   dirpath="checkpoints",
3   filename="best-checkpoint",
4   save_top_k=1,
5   verbose=True,
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'`
`how to fix it?`
````

Answer (score 1):

Very strange, maybe you install wrongly the pytorch lightning. I tried this in colab and no error:

```
!pip install lightning

import lightning.pytorch as pl
checkpoint_callback = pl.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath="checkpoints",
    filename="best-checkpoint",
    save_top_k=1,
    verbose=True,
    monitor="val_loss",
    mode="min"
)
```

Check if you imported it correctly.